# excel attendance sheet(macro)

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public rctr
Public cctr
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
    Call RCount
    Call CCount
    If Range("B" & rctr) = "" Then
    Range("A" & rctr).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(R2C:R[-1]C)"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & rctr & ":" & Cells(rctr, cctr - 1).Address), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("B" & rctr + 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C1-R[-1]C"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & rctr + 1 & ":" & Cells(rctr + 1, cctr - 1).Address), Type:=xlFillDefault

    Cells(1, cctr).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "TOTAL"
    Cells(2, cctr).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "COUNTA(RC2:RC[-1])"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, cctr).Address & ":" & Cells(rctr - 1, cctr).Address), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A1").Select
    Else
        Beep
    End If
End Sub
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
    Call RCount
    Call CCount
    If Range("B" & rctr) <> "" Then
    Range("A" & rctr - 1 & ":" & Cells(rctr, cctr).Address).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range(Cells(1, cctr - 1).Address & ":" & Cells(rctr, cctr - 1).Address).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select

    Else
        Beep
    End If

End Sub

Sub RCount()
    rctr = 1
    Do
        rctr = rctr + 1
    Loop While (Range("A" & rctr) <> "")
End Sub
Sub CCount()
    cctr = 1
    Do
        cctr = cctr + 1
    **Loop While (Cells("A" & cctr).Address <> "")** 
End Sub
```

I'm having a run time error 1004 Application defined or object define error with this loop . some one please help me. i dont know what to do. im newbie in VBA programming

Comment: Which line creates the error? I don't want to guess when you could just tell us.

Comment: Sub CCount()
    cctr = 1
    Do
        cctr = cctr + 1
    **Loop While (Cells("A" & cctr).Address <> "")** 
End Sub This one . the one have asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

I get a different error for your CCount procedure, but it should be `Range`, not `Cells`:

```
Sub CCount()
    cctr = 1
    Do
        cctr = cctr + 1
    Loop While (Range("A" & cctr).Address <> "")
End Sub
```

This then generates the error you stated, because it will loop to the last cell in the column and attempting to move to the next cell is an error - there is no next cell. A Range always has an `Address` so your condition <> "" is always met.

Your RCount procedure has the same problem.

If you want the total number of rows in a worksheet then it is just `Rows.Count`.